# How to update a Window instead of creating a new one in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program with my MainWindow and my Window1. I have some buttons and some labels in the MainWindow, when I press one it opens the Window1 (all those buttons open the same Window1 but with different content depending on the button I press). Then in Window1 I have a textbox and a button, when I press the button it has to fill one of the labels in the MainWindow, and it does, the problem is that when try to fill another label, it deletes the previous labels I filled.

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        if (sender.Equals(boton1))
        {
            window1.info.Content = "You pressed button 1";
        }
        else
        {
            window1.info.Content = "You pressed button 2";
        }
        window1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Window1:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    MainWindow main;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        main = new MainWindow();
        if (Convert.ToString(label.Content) == "You pressed button 1")
        {
            main.label1.Content = textBox.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            main.label2.Content = textBox.Text;
        }
        main.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

My complete project is a little different but larger. Sorry if you don't understand me, I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: You need to notify Property Changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399193/updating-wpf-control-in-real-time

Comment: @IlanKeshet sorry, how should I add it to my code?

Comment: look at the link, it as the full explaination in the answer

Comment: You will need to have Bindings on the Labels, instead of directly changing their content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said earlier you are creating a new MainWindow which is negating all of your previous changes, Try assigning the MainWindow as the Owner of Window1 that way you can reference back to the originating Window.

Something like this:
MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        if (sender.Equals(boton1))
        {
            window1.info.Content = "You pressed button 1";
        }
        else
        {
            window1.info.Content = "You pressed button 2";
        }
        window1.Owner = this;  //Note I am adding the Owner here
        window1.Show();
        Hide();               // I also am hiding the MainWindow instead of closing it.
    }
}
```

Window1:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    MainWindow main;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        main = (MainWindow)Owner;    /Note I am using the owner not creating a new MainWindow
        if (Convert.ToString(label.Content) == "You pressed button 1")
        {
            main.label1.Content = textBox.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            main.label2.Content = textBox.Text;
        }
        main.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because u re-creating MainWindow. Every time when you open new Window, u are creating new instance of MainWindow in this class, thats why old textbox are cleared.

Try something like this:

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        if (sender.Equals(boton1))
        {
            window1.info.Content = "You pressed button 1";
        }
        else
        {
            window1.info.Content = "You pressed button 2";
        }
        window1.ShowDialog();
        YourTexbox.Text = window1.YourText;

    }
}
```

Window1:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public string YourText {get; set;}

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (Convert.ToString(label.Content) == "You pressed button 1")
        {
            YourText = textBox.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            YourText  = textBox.Text;
        }
        this.Close();
    }
}
```